# Is it possible to not pad numerics with 0s when printing in r?

Tags: r

In r by default the [print method](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.default.html) seems to pad printed numbers with extra 0s to the right of the decimal place so that all of the numbers are displayed with the same number of decimals, which is equal to the maximum number of decimals.

For example

```
a <- c(5, 3.25, 7.9999)
b <- c(5.1, 3.2, 8.3)
data.frame(a, b)
```

yields

```
       a   b
1 5.0000 5.1
2 3.2500 3.2
3 7.9999 8.3
```

I know I can use `options` to change the maximum number of digits but that will just change the number of 0s added.   I don't want to change them to characters because I'd like to be able to work with the numbers afterwards. I just want to print the values as they are actually stored in the data frame (or other) object.

Is there any way to do that?

Note: This is not the same as asking how to set a fixed number of digits either generally or dynamically. The proposed duplicate questions address that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a `vector`, we can store it in `list` and that will preserve the digits as in the original

```
list(5, 3.25, 7.9999)
#[[1]]
#[1] 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 3.25

#[[3]]
#[1] 7.9999
```

If we really need a `data.frame`

```
data.frame(a = I(list(5, 3.25, 7.9999)), b = I(list(5.1, 3.2, 8.3)))
#      a   b
#1      5 5.1
#2   3.25 3.2
#3 7.9999 8.3
```

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not convinced that the elements of that data frame are still numeric. May need to use double [[ ]] to get numeric behaviour.

Comment: @user20637  It is a list column inside the `data.frame`.  If we check the `str` i.e. `str(data.frame(a = I(list(5, 3.25, 7.9999)), b = I(list(5.1, 3.2, 8.3))))#
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a:List of 3
  ..$ : num 5
  ..$ : num 3.25
  ..$ : num 8`

Comment: @akrun That is my point. Don't have R to hand now, but I guess, for example, 'plot(a, b)' or 'a*b' would not work.